# Why Typescript mapped type throws a compilation error

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, mapped-types

I have the following code:
[Typescript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECqEFMBO0DeAoaXoILZgEsQB%20ALmggBckCA7AcwG50BfddSgTwAcFoAxIpWQBFAK7JOAHgAqAPmgBeNJmwBtAArQ60ANYJOAewBm0GQF0yMzeeZt0dYUmNhgfAJLxkAJQTdDEASUhkjSMl4oCAAewrQAJjARChjY0MZ0cQDytAgAFOkgTuSChaISobJJAJTk4YhIduygkIn1AMrIAG4EbpX1ODEI8a3IyapYwIa0VEhiwMFIudw0nWDC0GL1vv6BC5zknlt%20AUEhYdUq49BsqVf0CJQRuXiEIOQzdPRVKqmplAAWBAgADpNj5jrszsD0vFsnlUDh8ERyC8iFgWFVmKk2CwgA)

```
class User {
    email?: string;
}

type FilterQuery<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]?:T[P];
}

interface IUserRepository<TUser extends User> {
    findOne(filter: FilterQuery<TUser>): TUser;
}

class UserService<TUser extends User> {
    constructor(private userRepository: IUserRepository<TUser>) {

    }

    getUser(email: string) {
        this.userRepository.findOne({ email: email });
    }
}
```

I get the following compilation error:

> Argument of type '{ email: string; }' is not assignable to parameter
> of type 'FilterQuery'.

I even get the correct auto-complete on `{ email: email }` so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the generic `TUser extends User`.  If if it just `User` with no generic then there is no error.

When you allow `TUser` to be something which extends `User`, you allow the possibility that `TUser` has a definition for `email` which is more specific than just `string`.

Suppose that the generic `TUser` for an instance of `UserService` is `{ email: 'literalstring@gmail.com'; }`.  This does extend `User` so no problem there.  But if you were to call `getUser('differentstring@gmail.com')` then you would have an invalid `FilterQuery`.  Not all `string` values are valid here.  `'literalstring@gmail.com'` is the only valid value for a `FilterQuery` of this instance.

If there is not a valid reason for the `UserService` to be a generic class, then remove the generics and base your repository type on `User`.

(note: I would have thought that changing the signature of `getUser` to `getUser(email: Required<TUser>['email'])` would have fixed it while keeping the generic, but it still gives an error and I can't really explain why).